# Generating pure html using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to extract a raw HTML table of data from a table which I currently generate on a web page using AngularJS.

To give a simple example:

Angular code:

```
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <td>{{customer.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.lastname}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I don't want to code two different solutions and so would like to use AngularJS.

Is it possible to extract the raw html code using AngularJS? i.e. the following :

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fred</td>
        <td>Bloggs</td>
    </tr>
    ...etc
  </table>
```

Comment: You should consider it render at server side then. Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232631/angularjs-server-side-rendering

Comment: I may go that route, so its a useful pointer. I would prefer to keep it client side if possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
  var element = angular.element(element)

   element[0] //show give raw dom element
```

refer jqlite and below link in angularJS , probably will get idea https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shushanthp/Lho8myw2/

Comment: Interesting. Looks like this could do the job. If you have a working example I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @JeffYates Glad to help :) , Its recommend and good approach to use directive for this , i have added the fiddle on the same , hope it helps

Comment: Perfect. Does the job. Very simple. Thanks @shushanth

Comment: @JeffYates :) :) . happy to help you jeff , no problem , :) ,