# is it possible to do server side rendering in angular JS(in older version i.e. version before 2.0)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, seo, nodes

I want to do server side rendering with angularJS. Is it possible to do it in older version of angularJS(version before 2.0)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few npm modules which parse AngularJS templates server-side:

> AngularJS-Server is built on jsdom, an implementation of the DOM API for Node, and angularcontext, which provides a lightweight container in which to instantiate your AngularJS application.
>
> After I eventually got a very basic AngularJS example running on the server, I moved on to routing. The first problem I ran into was that jsdom just stubs out the Window object's XMLHttpRequest, so it doesn't do anything. Solution was pretty simple -- modify a line in lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:

```
XMLHttpRequest: require('../../../../xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest
```

> Your angular app must use html5mode. The reason behind this requirement is that browsers don't send the hashbang fragment to the server.
>
> So for example, rendering on the server side http://domain.com/url#blah will just render http://domain.com/url.
>
> The library exposes several angular services, which will let you compile angular templates inside node

**References**

- [ng-node-compile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-node-compile)
- [AngularJS-server](https://github.com/a-lucas/angular.js-server)
- [Running AngularJS on the server with Node.js and jsdom](https://github.com/runvnc/angular-on-server/wiki/Running-AngularJS-on-the-server-with-Node.js-and-jsdom)
- [AngularJS - server-side rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232631/)
- [Getting Started with Benchpress](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2015/04/GettingStartedWithBenchpress.html)