# Server-side Rendering with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to do Server-side Rendering with AngularJS  ?
I have seen lots of tutorial using Angular 2 or more, but no ressources I have found about angularJS.
Is it at all possible ? and whats the way to go ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - server-side rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232631/angularjs-server-side-rendering)

Answer (score 1):

I have not experience on this topic with AngularJS. But if you are able to run an SSR on some node script it will be possible on firebase using Cloud Functions.

Try checking [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) first.